# Powershell get-content outofmemory

Tags: powershell, out-of-memory

I am having some issues with the following command:

```
Get-Content -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0 $FilePath_All, $FilePath_Int | Set-Content -Encoding Byte -Force $ImpDayFPath
```

The file is between 200-300MB.

I get an OutOfMemoryException. The machine has 8Gb but the error raises with only 4Gb used.

I checked the [Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx)

```
-ReadCount<Int64>

Specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a time. 
The default value is 1. A value of 0 (zero) sends all of the content at one time.

This parameter does not change the content displayed, but it does affect the time 
it takes to display the content. As the value of ReadCount increases, the time 
it takes to return the first line increases, but the total time for the operation 
decreases. This can make a perceptible difference in very large items.
```

I just wrote 0 because I couldn't find examples with benchmark test performance...

The files contain more or less 270k lines. Going one by one could create a problem in performance because I also have an external loop and the time would be O(n^2)

Any idea about the value I could use?

Comment: I need to get the content of legacy files and check if it is different or was modified(LastWriteTime) from the new one. The files are text-based

Comment: You are reading the whole file in one go (ReadCount 0), if you can compare line by line you could save a lot of memory.

Comment: Yes, I know, I checked the documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx But I am not familiar with this and couldn't choose a "common value".

Comment: To quickly check differences between files, usually a specialized command works better than PowerShell (it has `Compare-Objects`, but that's not exactly efficient). The good old `diff` utility (which in PowerShell is an alias for `Compare-Objects`, so don't confuse it with that) was written to do this and do it well. PowerShell falls flat on its face rather quickly if you're using it for anything not line-based.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading binary data, I'm not sure if you can actually change the amount of lines being streamed through the pipeline using the Get-Content cmdlet, based on what I have found on the official documentation. Here is a relevant paragraph I found on TechNet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847788.aspx):

> "When reading from and writing to binary files, use a value of Byte for the Encoding dynamic parameter and a value of 0 for the ReadCount parameter. A ReadCount value of 0 reads the entire file in a single read operation and converts it into a single object (PSObject). The default ReadCount value, 1, reads one byte in each read operation and converts each byte into a separate object, which causes errors when you use the Set-Content cmdlet to write the bytes to a file. For more information, see the examples."

However, it might be possible to read in large files (in binary format I'm assuming), using the BinaryReader class found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx. Or or for huge binary files, using the UnmanagedMemoryStream .Net Class, which doesn't cap the amount of memory being used. Details can be found here...
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Compare-Object can be used to compare the contents of files. Consider the following code:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content .\file1.txt) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content .\file2.txt)
```

The default behaviour is to only show the differences between the files. Knowing this we could test for difference like this:

```
if (-not(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content .\file1.txt) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content .\file2.txt))) {
    Write-Output 'Files are equal'
}
else {
    Write-Output 'Files are not equal'
}
```